# How to use if else in yaml?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

Below is a snippet of yaml I am using. I want to call yaml say abc.yml if a variable ENV is set to, say 'abc', and xyz.yml if the variable ( passed as a parameter ) is set to 'xyz'. How do I use if condition in the yaml ?

```
 script:
   - ansible-playbook -i <dir> pqr.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "
   - ansible-playbook -i <dir> abc.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "
   - ansible-playbook -i <dir> xyz.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "
   - ansible-playbook -i <dir> hjk.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can, using [conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages).

The example could be something like below:

- I used an input parameter as example, any variable will do
- I separated the scripts in jobs
- Adding `condition` will take care of any validation and can therefore skip the job

```yaml
parameters:

  - name: whatToRunVar
    displayName: 'What should it be: abc or xyz?'
    default: ''
    type: string

jobs:
  - job: pqr
    steps:
    - script: ansible-playbook -i <dir> pqr.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "

  - job: abc
    steps:
    - script: ansible-playbook -i <dir> abc.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "
    condition: contains('${{ parameters.whatToRunVar}}', 'abc')

  - job: xyz
    steps:
    - script: ansible-playbook -i <dir> xyz.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "l
    condition: contains('${{ parameters.whatToRunVar}}', 'xyz')
    
  - job: hjk
    steps:
    - script: ansible-playbook -i <dir> hjk.yaml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}.... "
```

Submitting `abcde` as parameter results in:
[image: run with abcde]

Comment: Can we add jobs: in between multiple scripts ? Actually there are multiple ansible-playbok lines in the script and I require the condition check on only 2 ( as mentioned in the question).

Comment: Add other jobs in between won't be a problem, as long as they don't have a condition. The condition part of job abc or xyz is letting it run or not, it won't affect other jobs

Comment: ok. And instead of equal condition, I want to check for a substring condition. How do I do that ?

Comment: It's not working that way. Adding jobs: section inside scripts: is giving errors. Any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: I hope it gives you an idea now. I want the conditional check just for abc and xyz

Comment: updated the example, with all 4 ansible-playbook scenarios, implemented `contains` and even tested it. What do you think @Shivani?

Comment: I guess you didn't get the scenario. The conditional step is to be used only for abc and pqr. Rest of the steps are mandatory irrespective of the ENV paramater.

Comment: Maybe I completely misunderstood you, but in the question you write abc as well as xyz to be evaluated. 
In my answer I just added the parameter as an example so I could test it, another variable will also work.
With `condition` you can skip any jobs and so achieve your goal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250249/discussion-between-promicro-and-shivani).

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code did the trick:

```
 script:
- if [[ ${ENV} =~ "abc" ]]; then MODULE="abc"; else MODULE="xyz"; fi
- ansible-playbook -i $CI_PROJECT_DIR/ansible/${HOSTFILE} ${MODULE}_installation.yml --verbose -f 10 -e "ENV=${ENV}...
```